# How to merge text based on a specific condition

Tags: arrays, excel-formula, textjoin

I'm consolidating some questionnaires in Excel, in fact, over 50 questionnaires with more than 100 Lines with 3 individual questions in Each. The Numeric answer I can quantify, the problem is the text.

I can only think into consolidate all questionnaires by copying and pasting in the botton and then quantifying by using textjoin with IF. The real deal is that we probably gonna have to textjoin more than 50 texts based on the name of the question.  Is there anyway to do this? The Logic is something like this:

```
=WHERE A:A="Question 1"; Then Textjoin("|";0;C:C)
```

I know Excel has no Where, but i found this the best way to explain

I Tried Used Textjoin, but I'd have to select cell by cell over 50 thousand lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FILTER` to return "Question 1" rows only:

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",0,FILTER(tblData[Answer],tblData[Question]="Question 1"))
```

[image]